# AWS Elastic Beanstalk "composer install" fails to find packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using git to deploy a Laravel app to Elastic Beanstalk, however the app always fails to deploy. I checked the logs and here are the errors I get:

```
Problem 1
- The requested package laravel/framework could not be found in any version, there may be       a typo in the package name.
Problem 2
- The requested package laravelbook/ardent could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 3
- The requested package machuga/authority-l4 could not be found in any version, there may  be a typo in the package name.
Problem 4
- The requested package way/generators could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 5
- The requested package jonob/restful could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 6
- The requested package intervention/image could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 7
- cartalyst/api 1.0.x-dev requires illuminate/container 4.0.* -> no matching package found.
- cartalyst/api v1.0.0 requires illuminate/container 4.0.* -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for cartalyst/api 1.0.* -> satisfiable by cartalyst/api v1.0.0, cartalyst/api 1.0.x-dev.
```

and here is my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
    "cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*",
        "cartalyst/api": "1.0.*",
        "machuga/authority-l4" : "dev-master",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "jonob/restful": "dev-master",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.cartalyst.com"
    }
    ],
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

It seems to find the cartalyst packages alright, so maybe I need to specify a repository for the others? If so, what would that repository be?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. The composer.lock file was in .gitignore and so composer on AWS didn't get it... See here for more details: http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/08/19/solving-the-elastic-beanstalk-composer-deployment-problems/